# How to compare relative weight of two subsets?

Tags: probability, distributions, weights, methodology

For one experiment, I have two data sources A and B contributing data points, and a function that takes the union of the sets of datapoints and assigns a quality weight to each point.

I'm trying to analyze the quality of A vs B over many such experiments to evaluate if B is "as good" of a data source as A is. One basic thing to do is to count for how many experiments A vs B had the higher sum of weights. But that doesn't capture cases where A and B are end up both capturing about half of the total weight. Is there some statistical method I could use to quantify B's relative goodness vs A? I also tried making a histogram of the ratio of B's total weight to A's total weight, but that ends up being such a wide distribution of values that it wasn't very easy to analyze.

Comment: Are these paired samples (1 B for each A)? What about a histogram of the difference of the scores?

Comment: Each experiment has an A set and a B set, the number of elements in each set may be different though. Sometimes one set will be much smaller than the other.

Comment: It's hard to advise here without more information about the nature of the "quality weights". Maybe provide notional weights for a couple experiments. If A has more points than B, but they are of lower "quality", explain why it is better to compare the sums of the quality weights rather than, say, the mean of the quality weights.